# Software for plotting functions... Any suggestions?

Tags: soft-question, math-software

I'm looking for a (hopefully cheap/free) software that could plot functions for academic use.

Until this point, I used MATLAB as a primary tool to draw graphs. Although it 'could' plot any functions I need, actually I feel it is often too tedious and time-consuming to make a nice-looking plot by manipulating scripts.

Something with a simple and formal UI and the capacity to draw implicit/parametric functions would be ideal. Also, I don't care spending a few dollars on good software; so any suggestions would be welcome(except i do care about hundreds of dollars so please leave out Mathematica) :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Sometimes implicit equations are hard to plot in the usual softwares. I use [Surfex](http://surfex.algebraicsurface.net/) for this. Pretty simple to use and produces nice looking plots.

Comment: Are u student or employe at university?
In both cases Wolfram Mathematica will be most probably offered via your university with free license. I certainly suggest you to use it since other software is either numerical as Matlab or agebraic but less capable as Maple. I used all of them for some time but Mathematica inspired me most =D... Besides, the documentation is really really good!

Comment: Mathematica also comes bundled with raspberry-pi computers now for free, so that's a petty cheap way to get it legally. Non commercial license of course.

Answer (score 2):

If you are a Mac user, Apple bundles for free a really neat mathematical graphing application called *Grapher* which you can find in the Applications/Utilities folder.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapher

It does everything you ask, including implicit, polar, parametric, fancy 3d plots and animations, live 3D rotations, ... with an elegant user interface too.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the [Java Graphers](http://dlippman.imathas.com/g1/GrapherLaunch.html) by David Lippman very quick and easy if you don't want to use a bona-fide math software package.

Answer (score 1):

Maxima CAS :

1. implicit plot : [standard](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/docs/manual/maxima_12.html#Item_003a-implicit_005fplot)  or [draw package](http://riotorto.users.sourceforge.net/gnuplot/implic/index.html)
2. [parametric plot](http://riotorto.users.sourceforge.net/gnuplot/parametric/index.html)

HTH

Adam